# ember.js: combine search and filter

Tags: ember.js

Having this controller:

```
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend Ember.PaginationMixin,
  sortProperties: ["number"]
```

I would like to add the "search" functionality, in this (working) way

```
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend Ember.PaginationMixin,
  sortProperties: ["number"]
  search: ''
  filteredContent: (->
    search = @get("search")
    @get("content").filter (item)->
      name = item.get("name").toLowerCase()
      name.match(search.toLowerCase())
  ).property("submittedSearch")

  filterContent: ->
    @set "submittedSearch", @get("search")
```

The problem is that when I apply my search i'm losing my sorting defined before. What could I do?

Comment: Losing the order of what ?

Comment: which version of ember are you using?

Comment: @Unspecified loosing my sort order.

Answer (score 1):

**From the official documentation**

> `Ember.SortableMixin` provides a standard interface for
>   array proxies to specify a sort order and maintain this sorting when
>   objects are added, removed, or updated ***without changing the
>   implicit order of their underlying content array:***

`Ember.SortableMixin` only cares about the `content` array while we do get, here you're trying to do get on `filteredContent` which the mixin doesn;t care !

So what I'd suggest you is make the `content` as computed property which depends on selected search as follows,

```
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend Ember.PaginationMixin,
  sortProperties: ["number"]
  search: ''
  content: (->
    search = @get("search")
    @get('products').filter (item) ->
      name = item.get("name").toLowerCase()
      name.match(search.toLowerCase())
  ).property('submittedSearch')
```

Inside the route `setupController` set the main list to `products` property of controller instead of `content`

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupControllers: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('products'), App.Products.find()
```

Now, your `content` would be filtered courtesy ComputedProperty, sorted courtesy the "mixin"

Comment: there is only a little problem: any change on the `submittedSearch` variable does not trigger the recalculation of `content`. The same code applied to another variable does trigger.

Comment: what are you doing with the content ? I mean displaying the list on UI or what is your use case ?

Comment: i'm just listing the content in the usual way: `{{#each controller}} {{this.name}}{{/each}}`

Comment: Can you come up with a jsfiddle ?, so that I can see exactly whats going wrong, its hard to interpret this way

Comment: well the fiddle is in coffeescript, your problem solved by the way ?